# Helm dependency condition

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, kubernetes-helm

is there a way to set condition in Chart.yaml file based on variable existency? I want to install dependency just when the variable `SERVICE_A_URL` is not set. I tried these but helm always try to install dependency.

```
condition: "not SERVICE_A_URL"
condition: "not defined SERVICE_A_URL"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written [in documentation:](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-dependencies)

> All charts are loaded by default. If tags or condition fields are
> present, they will be evaluated and used to control loading for the
> chart(s) they are applied to.

> Condition - The condition field holds one or more YAML paths
> (delimited by commas). If this path exists in the top parent's values
> and resolves to a boolean value, the chart will be enabled or disabled
> based on that boolean value. Only the first valid path found in the
> list is evaluated and if no paths exist then the condition has no
> effect.

If there is no path specified or there is nothing associated with the path the condition has no effect. You can disable installing the dependency in the `values.yaml` file.

For example, if you have following `Chart.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  - name: subchart1
    condition: subchart1.enabled
    tags:
      - front-end
      - subchart1
```

and you want to disable charts tagged `back-end`, in `values.yaml` you have to assign `false` value to it:

```
subchart1:
  enabled: true
tags:
  front-end: false
  back-end: true
```